# A basis for a plane containing the origin.

Tags: linear-algebra

I need to show that the set $\{(1,-1,0),(0,1,-1)\}$ forms a basis for the subspace $V\subset \mathbb{R}^3$ wherein $V=\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3 \ \vert \ x+y+z=0\}.$ I tried to show that from the equation $x+y+z=0$ can be rewritten with parameters as $(x,y,z)=s(-1,1,0)+t(-1,0,1) \ s,t\in\mathbb{R}$ but this is not the basis given.

Comment: yes, you can put $s=y$ and $t=z$

Comment: I meant that the basis I ascertained was $\{(-1,1,0),(-1,0,1)\}$.

Answer (score 2):

By substitution, both given vectors satisfy the equation and therefore lie in the plane.

As the two vectors are not scalar multiples of each other, they are linearly independent.

Two linearly independent vectors in a plane form a basis for that plane.

**Note** that proving a given set forms a basis is frequently easier than actually finding a basis from scratch.  If you were asked to find a basis, the working you have done would be good and your answer would be
$$\{(-1,1,0),\,(-1,0,1)\}$$
which is fine.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do now is express those two vectors as a linear combination of your desired basis vectors. For example: $(-1,1,0)=-(1,-1,0)$. Can you figure out the second one?